# Update text field value each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am using a jquery dialog box and in that I need to have some text field with required data.

This dialog box opens when we click a button which then contains 4 input text fields and these input has to be auto complete based on the data 
of button which is clicked.

Here I created a code that have one text field and it value is getting from valueofText which is updated each time on click. I have also used 
console to check whether value is updating or not.

My code is

```
        valueofText  = row //changes every time

        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
          .html('<form>Enter email address <input id=emailAddresss type="text"></form>')
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               height: 300,
               width: 500,
               draggable: false,
               title: "Some title",

               open: function (event, ui) {
                 //  $("#emailAddresss").val(valueofText);
               console.log("id is  "+valueofText);
                 document.getElementById('emailAddresss').value = valueofText;
               $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
               }
              });
             $("#emailAddresss").val('');
             $dialog.dialog('open');
```

My problem is it updates only once then if we open modal window again it does not show any value. What is wrong am I doing here?

Comment: i think your creating the dialog on every click with out deleting the old one. This means the value will be changed for the first crated dialog (since emailAddresss is an id) which is closed, but you are opening a new created dialog

Comment: so how I can resolve this?

Comment: posted a possible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the `emailAdresss` child of current dialog, like:

```
$(this).find('#emailAddresss').val(valueofText);
```

See following example, where I've created 4 dialogs:

```js
var html = '<form>Enter email address <input id="emailAddresss" type="text"></form>';

function openDialog(valueofText){
  var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
  .html(html)
  .dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 250,
    draggable: false,
    title: "Some title",

    open: function (event, ui) {
      console.log("id is  "+valueofText);
      $(this).find('#emailAddresss')
      .val(valueofText);
      $(this).css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }
  });
  $dialog.dialog('open');
}

for(valueofText=1; valueofText<5; valueofText++){
  openDialog(valueofText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your creating the dialog on every click with out deleting the old one. This means the value will be changed for the first crated dialog (since `emailAddresss` is an id) which is closed, but you are opening a new created dialog.

If I'm right you have 2 choices:

1. Delete an old dialog before creating new.
   Create dialog with an id  `var $dialog = $('<div id="myDialog"></div>')` and before creating a new one remove it `$('#dialog').remove();`
2. Create a dialog only once on page load (even better put it as html) and on click only change `emailAddress` input and open the dialog.